# Automatically redirect to a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, blocking

For some reason, medium.com is not available where I live.

Though, it is accessible via a VPN connection which in part takes some minutes in the process of opening the app, finding a server, and establishing a connection, making the whole process too uneasy to just view an article.

Is there some way to automatically redirect to some VPN/Proxy when the browser detects I'm trying to view a webpage from Medium?

Comment: Quick thought without any testing, etc. but you could have a machine or VM, etc. always connected to the vpn that forward traffic and then set a static route for the IP address of the website to go to the IP address of the server that's always connected to the VPN. Again, quick thought only with no confirmation, etc. and just a thought but what have you tried already?

Comment: I'm thinking of a more natural way to handle it as I need the performance of a host machine and the speedy connection of a non-vpn one. (A one that works in everyday tasks) @PimpJuiceIT

Comment: If it's that critical and you confirm/verify that using a VM is not performing good enough, simply use a dedicated machine with a high throughput NIC on a high throughput port on a router/switch, etc. You will still point the routes accordingly and setup the IP forwarding on the VPN host regardless I would think.